# Display output from command and save to file

Tags: terminal

If I wanted to save output to a file from a command like make, I would do:

```
make > out.txt
```

However that stops the output from being displayed on the console window, and only saves to a file.

Is there a way to display output from a monitoring process, or a long make command and save it to a file?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the `tee` command to send output to the screen and write the same contents to a file.

```
make | tee output.txt
```

If you want to append to the target file (like the `>> output.txt` redirection) instead of overwriting it, you should add the `-a` option to `tee`:

```
make | tee -a output.txt
```

Comment: Lovely. Short and clear.